# Jquery Datepicker - Show the date based on the User's custom Timezone saved in database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, jquery-ui-datepicker

In my Rails application, there is a requirement that a user can choose a working location and he should be able to work on that timezone in the application no matter where ever he is. So, a particular timezone will be there corresponding to each user.

E.g., I got a job in Australia, but working as remote from India. So, even if he is accessing the system from India, he should be able to use the system in Australian Timezone. So, the jquery calendar also needs to be displayed according to Australian Timezone.

Timezones available in Rails:

```
1.9.3-p484 :001 > ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.sort
 => [(GMT-11:00) American Samoa, (GMT-11:00) International Date Line West, (GMT-11:00) Midway Island, (GMT-10:00) Hawaii, (GMT-09:00) Alaska, (GMT-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada), (GMT-08:00) Tijuana, (GMT-07:00) Arizona, (GMT-07:00) Chihuahua, (GMT-07:00) Mazatlan, (GMT-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada), (GMT-06:00) Central America, (GMT-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada), (GMT-06:00) Guadalajara, (GMT-06:00) Mexico City, (GMT-06:00) Monterrey, (GMT-06:00) Saskatchewan, (GMT-05:00) Bogota, (GMT-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada), (GMT-05:00) Indiana (East), (GMT-05:00) Lima, (GMT-05:00) Quito, (GMT-04:30) Caracas, (GMT-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada), (GMT-04:00) Georgetown, (GMT-04:00) La Paz, (GMT-03:30) Newfoundland, (GMT-03:00) Brasilia, (GMT-03:00) Buenos Aires, (GMT-03:00) Greenland, (GMT-03:00) Santiago, (GMT-02:00) Mid-Atlantic, (GMT-01:00) Azores, (GMT-01:00) Cape Verde Is., (GMT+00:00) Casablanca, (GMT+00:00) Dublin, (GMT+00:00) Edinburgh, (GMT+00:00) Lisbon, (GMT+00:00) London, (GMT+00:00) Monrovia, (GMT+00:00) UTC, (GMT+01:00) Amsterdam, (GMT+01:00) Belgrade, (GMT+01:00) Berlin, (GMT+01:00) Bern, (GMT+01:00) Bratislava, (GMT+01:00) Brussels, (GMT+01:00) Budapest, (GMT+01:00) Copenhagen, (GMT+01:00) Ljubljana, (GMT+01:00) Madrid, (GMT+01:00) Paris, (GMT+01:00) Prague, (GMT+01:00) Rome, (GMT+01:00) Sarajevo, (GMT+01:00) Skopje, (GMT+01:00) Stockholm, (GMT+01:00) Vienna, (GMT+01:00) Warsaw, (GMT+01:00) West Central Africa, (GMT+01:00) Zagreb, (GMT+02:00) Athens, (GMT+02:00) Bucharest, (GMT+02:00) Cairo, (GMT+02:00) Harare, (GMT+02:00) Helsinki, (GMT+02:00) Istanbul, (GMT+02:00) Jerusalem, (GMT+02:00) Kyiv, (GMT+02:00) Pretoria, (GMT+02:00) Riga, (GMT+02:00) Sofia, (GMT+02:00) Tallinn, (GMT+02:00) Vilnius, (GMT+03:00) Baghdad, (GMT+03:00) Kuwait, (GMT+03:00) Minsk, (GMT+03:00) Moscow, (GMT+03:00) Nairobi, (GMT+03:00) Riyadh, (GMT+03:00) St. Petersburg, (GMT+03:00) Volgograd, (GMT+03:30) Tehran, (GMT+04:00) Abu Dhabi, (GMT+04:00) Baku, (GMT+04:00) Muscat, (GMT+04:00) Tbilisi, (GMT+04:00) Yerevan, (GMT+04:30) Kabul, (GMT+05:00) Ekaterinburg, (GMT+05:00) Islamabad, (GMT+05:00) Karachi, (GMT+05:00) Tashkent, (GMT+05:30) Chennai, (GMT+05:30) Kolkata, (GMT+05:30) Mumbai, (GMT+05:30) New Delhi, (GMT+05:30) Sri Jayawardenepura, (GMT+05:45) Kathmandu, (GMT+06:00) Almaty, (GMT+06:00) Astana, (GMT+06:00) Dhaka, (GMT+06:00) Novosibirsk, (GMT+06:00) Urumqi, (GMT+06:30) Rangoon, (GMT+07:00) Bangkok, (GMT+07:00) Hanoi, (GMT+07:00) Jakarta, (GMT+07:00) Krasnoyarsk, (GMT+08:00) Beijing, (GMT+08:00) Chongqing, (GMT+08:00) Hong Kong, (GMT+08:00) Irkutsk, (GMT+08:00) Kuala Lumpur, (GMT+08:00) Perth, (GMT+08:00) Singapore, (GMT+08:00) Taipei, (GMT+08:00) Ulaan Bataar, (GMT+09:00) Osaka, (GMT+09:00) Sapporo, (GMT+09:00) Seoul, (GMT+09:00) Tokyo, (GMT+09:00) Yakutsk, (GMT+09:30) Adelaide, (GMT+09:30) Darwin, (GMT+10:00) Brisbane, (GMT+10:00) Canberra, (GMT+10:00) Guam, (GMT+10:00) Hobart, (GMT+10:00) Magadan, (GMT+10:00) Melbourne, (GMT+10:00) Port Moresby, (GMT+10:00) Solomon Is., (GMT+10:00) Sydney, (GMT+10:00) Vladivostok, (GMT+11:00) New Caledonia, (GMT+12:00) Auckland, (GMT+12:00) Fiji, (GMT+12:00) Kamchatka, (GMT+12:00) Marshall Is., (GMT+12:00) Wellington, (GMT+13:00) Nuku'alofa, (GMT+13:00) Samoa, (GMT+13:00) Tokelau Is.]
```

I think, the jquery datepicker takes browser timezone by default. How that can be customized according to our requirement meaning how we can apply a particular timezone to jquery datepicker?

Answer (score 0):

Try customizing the datepicker using dateFormat function https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat by adding a new date value like

```
var currentFormat = "mm/dd/y";
var dateValue1 = new Date("Mon Mar 30 2020 06:00:00 GMT+0200 (Romance Daylight Time)");
var dateValue2 = new Date("Mon Mar 30 2020 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Romance Daylight Time)"

document.body.innerHTML += $.datepicker.formatDate(currentFormat, dateValue1) + "<br />";
document.body.innerHTML += $.datepicker.formatDate(currentFormat, dateValue2) + "<br />";
```